# Sharepoint online event receiver: No options for the event source item field

Tags: sharepoint-online, event-receivers

I'm trying to create a basic event receiver that will force version comments on check-in of documents. I've opened a blank SP2013 project in VS2013. I clicked project>add new item and selected event receiver. This brings me to the Sharepoint customization wizard; within the wizard there is the field 'What item should be the event source' The dropdown menu displays no options and I can't enter anything manually.

I'm wondering if anyone knows why this field is empty, and what I need to do to proceed.

Comment: You should provide repro steps. On-prem/online? Full-trust/sandbox? Solution/App...

Comment: The eventual goal is to upload this solution to a sharepoint online site, so it will be a sandbox solution. My understanding is that it will need to be developed in visual studio on a VM with SPfoundation and VS tools installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In solution explorer, select the project. Then, in the properties window, ensure the Site Url points to a site collection on the same computer.

Comment: Thanks Paul. It seems that a change has been made to the server I'm working on such that VS still recognizes the site as valid but the test environment has actually been moved or removed.